# Tag beginners questions page

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, new-users

Imagine someone new coming to SO to ask about Java, in most cases their questions will be duplicates. Same thing in Travel.SE, someone coming to ask how to book a ticket, etc.

Now, if there was a page in each SE site, with the following features:

- It contains questions targeting beginners in a specific field covered by the site, for example Java. The section is also a tag.
- The questions selected to show in this page are voted for by top users/mods in the site.
- The page to be advertised for new users when posting a new question, the tags and/or the title can be used to figure it out.
- Can also be advertised for new users who recently asked questions.
- The selected questions to be shown in the tag info page under a section called "Beginners questions".
- The list itself should be simple, as any other list page. SE specific information such as score should be removed in that listing page, to make it easier for the new guys who are not familiar with SE.

[image: beginners section]

One can argue that users can check the suggested questions list, but that's a different thing. This page will cover larger area for new users. It actually might help them and save the site some extra duplicates.

Comment: Probably around 80% of duplicates arise from when people don't search at all. If they did, then the duplicates are good for themselves, as well as others: we get signposts to good quality content. By separating the "new users" from the "professionals", you create divisions, which will just destroying each individual group, and the entire site, in the long run.

Comment: Oh hah! So this is what you meant. I already downvoted it in chat, so I'm not voting here. The problem with this request of yours is that we're essentially making a beautiful page we'd appreciate but one that has no use. The worst questions come from people who only read the words on the buttons "sign up" and "log in" before asking their question.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. this is something totally else! what I meant in chat was already there I just didnt notice it before.

Answer (score 7):

What you are proposing isn't actually that new and some parts are already there.

If you look for example at the top questions on a tag, for example [those of the feature-request tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes), you will already see the posts that are useful to the majority, judging its votes.

Also, when composing a question, you get the 'possible duplicates' suggestions while you type. There is already a great chance those have the the answer to the question.

The thing that is really new to your proposal is that there is more visibility on what useful information can be found in the tags used on a question. I think not that much new users know that the tag wiki page actually has a lot of useful information. If we get that to the user, I am happy.

Also, the Documentation beta on Stack Overflow is another way to achieve just this. If that is linked from the Ask page, a lot of users can be helped.

Still, this won't help users who don't read and just ask a question. That is the biggest problem in the network in my opinion.